# Anti de Sitter space

Tags: general-relativity, curvature, cosmological-inflation, anti-de-sitter-spacetime

1. While writing the metric for AdS Space, why are we starting with a five dimensional Flat space and embedding a hyperboloid in it?
2. Does it have to do with the fact that the cosmological constant being negative?

Comment: FWIW, a positive  cosmological constant leads to a similar construction for de Sitter space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Embedding the AdS 4D spacetime as a hypersurface in a 5D manifold is just a convenient way of studying it. There is no physical meaning to the 5D manifold - it is just a mathematical device.

Any 4D spacetime can be embedded in a manifold of higher dimensionality, though it turns out to be surprisingly complicated to specify what dimensionality the manifold has to be. See [this question in the Math Overflow for more on this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/127734/nash-embedding-theorems-for-pseudo-riemannian-manifolds).

So, no, the embedding is not specifically related to a negative cosmological constant. De Sitter space can be embedded in a 5D manifold in the same way, and indeed as Robert Greene's work tells us any spacetime can be embedded, though in general the dimensionality required will be higher than five.

Comment: Any 4D vacuum solution of GR can be embedded in a flat 5D canonical space with a cosmological constant. There is a number of publications on this topic. This paper specifically mentions the implications for the cosmological constant in AdS: https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1011/1011.0214.pdf - And this one specifies the effective cosmological constant in general: https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/0705/0705.0067.pdf

Comment: Then, while driving the metric where do we use the fact that the cosmological constant is negative?

Comment: @Khushal: I'm not sure what you're asking. Assuming you mean *deriving* rather than *driving*, the AdS metric is the vacuum solution to the Einstein equation with a negative value of $\Lambda$.